# How to give mouse click event on placemark on marble widget?

Tags: qt, marble

I am working on KDE Marble.
https://marble.kde.org/
I can give mouse click and mouse move event on MarbleWidget (mouseClickGeoPosition and mouseMoveGeoPosition).
http://api.kde.org/4.6-api/kdeedu-apidocs/marble/html/classMarble_1_1MarbleWidget.html
but i can't give mouse click event on Placemark. i need a signal that give me position and name when click on one of the Placemarks. Thanks!

Comment: Did you ever find a solution? I'm looking for the same thing

Comment: Unfortunately this question has never been answered in the Marble KDE forum as well: [https://forum.kde.org/viewtopic.php?f=217&t=135502](https://forum.kde.org/viewtopic.php?f=217&t=135502). The project doesn't seem to be really active for some time.

Answer (score -1):

you can use this code

```
          jWidget->whichFeatureAt(QPoint(["your Mouse Position"]));
```

Comment: This does not work for placemarks and geometries in general. See: [https://forum.kde.org/viewtopic.php?f=217&t=125613](https://forum.kde.org/viewtopic.php?f=217&t=125613)
So far I have not found a suitable option for detecting clicks on placemarks.